# React Native button click with Android requires random number of multiple clicks

Tags: android, react-native

With React Native, I'm experienced different behavior when clicking buttons on iOS vs android?
On android I am getting a very strange behavior - randomly it executes or doesn't the button click I can see it getting pressed, but it's not always doing what it's supposed to do.
Sometimes requires 5 taps, sometimes 2, sometimes works right away.

Comment: Are you using an AVD? The Android emulator is notoriously slow and may not be responding to touches properly

Comment: No. An actual device. A crappy android phone - Galaxy J7